# CSV files downloads (opened in Excel) prompt for Windows User Authentication

Tags: java, excel, authentication, weblogic

I have a site using a self-signed cert (which prompts for "trust this site and continue"), and in IE, occasionally when the user attempts to download a CSV file (which is handled by writing the file to the file system and sending a redirect header), the user can be prompted with the Windows authentication screen for username/password.

This has been observed in XP/Windows-7 in IE7 and IE8. This **only** happens when our site has an incorrect certificate and the user attempts to download a file with opens in Excel. What could be happening?

Fixing the certificate is one fix, but I'd like to have this working regardless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no solution, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

[This article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2019105) may be useful. Try using setting a `Content-Disposition: attachment` header on the redirect.

Comment: This isn't very helpful. The file download is handled through weblogic, so I can't really directly tie into the response headers for this specific case.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a guess.  It may be that the file is marked as coming from an outside domain, i.e. the Internet (which is recorded in a NTFS Alternate Data Stream, I believe).  Security policy requires a confirmation to open the potentially unsafe file, and that causes a UAC prompt.  This is based on the assumption that the "Windows authentication screen for username/password" you reference is UAC and not the IE browser asking for basic authentication.